# Which are the set of needed Server side permissions to download a google sheet from Google Drive in my Android app

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-signin

My specific issue is

when I call

```
driveService.files().export(fileId, "text/csv").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

From my App I get

```
11-22 00:35:02.489 : com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
11-22 00:35:02.490 : {
11-22 00:35:02.491 :  "error": {
11-22 00:35:02.491 :   "errors": [
11-22 00:35:02.491 :    {
11-22 00:35:02.491 :     "domain": "global",
11-22 00:35:02.491 :     "reason": "authError",
11-22 00:35:02.491 :     "message": "Invalid Credentials",
11-22 00:35:02.492 :     "locationType": "header",
11-22 00:35:02.492 :     "location": "Authorization"
11-22 00:35:02.492 :    }
11-22 00:35:02.492 :   ],
11-22 00:35:02.492 :   "code": 401,
11-22 00:35:02.492 :   "message": "Invalid Credentials"
11-22 00:35:02.493 :  }
11-22 00:35:02.493 : }
```

When I use APIs Explorer on 
Services / Drive API v3 / drive.files.export
I get the data I want.

### My Questions are:

1. How can I fix this issue.
2. As I get a google account when I sign in... is that not enough to know the user/password I've entered and which is registered in the smartphone ...Am I right?
3. Which are the minimal set of permissions I need to set in servers side in order to have permissions
4. How can I check which is the specific permission issue that does not allow to download the google sheet from google drive?

Thanks a lot for any response.

### My Java code snippets related to this issue (sign in process)

## In server side

My credentials for the app are:

- Web client
- Android Client

I use the Client id of "Web client"
If I use the clientId of Android client I don't get the idToken

Enabled Library API:

- Google Drive API
      Authorize requests using Oauth 2.0 - On drive.files.export
- Google Sheet API

## In Android App

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(this.googleClientId)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    ...

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    ...
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    ...

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        validateGoogleUser(data);
    }
}

...
    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(this.dataIntent);
...
    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
...
    // It returns my account with id / idToken / mail / names / ... more


    And then... I continue
```

In the method I try to download this is the code

```
        //TODO: move this to a service and to a dao
        final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT  = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();;
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);



        Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(applicationName)
                .build();
        String fileId = idSheet;
        //TODO: Check how to check progress and limit size of download or cancel the operation after n seconds
        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        driveService.files().export(fileId, "text/csv")
                .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

NOTE : I don't use 
    - GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify

nor I know for what it is ... as I already get my account info.

Comment: Try following [Android](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/quickstart) or [Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) quickstart. They both have different client ID types, the first is for Android application which requires you to create Signing-certificate fingerprint while the later is for using Web application client IDs. As long as the scope you are using is not readonly or to be sure, use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` this will allow you to any access to read, download, write or upload file content.

Comment: Thanks... I will check it. I understand now that surely the problem is in the way I'm creating the credential object        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);  I will check that code and also found many others that solve the sign in process in different ways using diverse classes from diverse packages.... Buy I will check the one you mention.... Thanks

Comment: About the fingerprint I'm using the android debug provided certificate in debug environment. And the last error I got with credentials is      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid 10058 lacks any of android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS    trying to apply the solution in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GlFZ1wWUk4

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution of the problem. The rights of the server side were ok. But in this project I've forked is the combination of Google Sign in and Google drive connection I need to download or use Google Drive files from my Android app

https://github.com/jguastav/android-GoogleDriveSample